# Change of variable and integration of a rational function $\int \frac{x^4 - 1}{x + \sqrt{x}}.dx$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to resolve an exercise from a book

$$ \int \frac{x^4 - 1}{x + \sqrt{x}}.dx$$

His author puts it as an easy one, and gives its solution:
$\frac{x^5}{5} - \ln{x} + (\frac{2}{3})x^\frac{3}{2} + C$, with $C \in \mathbb{R}$

My problem, of course, it's that I'm not finding the path to go to that solution...

I believe I have to treat this function as rational one, having either (or both) to

- convert it to a sum of polynoms
- do a variable change

But, whatever I remove the square root or not, I stumble upon a problem that looks too difficult to solve:

If I do this:

$\int \frac{x^4 - 1}{x + \sqrt{x}}.dx = \int \frac{x^4 - 1}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x} + 1)}.dx = \int (\frac{C}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{D}{\sqrt{x} + 1}).dx$

$= \int \frac{C(\sqrt{x} + 1) + D(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x} + 1)}.dx = \int \frac{\sqrt{x}(C+D) + C}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x} + 1)}.dx$

This leads me to identify:

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ C(X) + D(X) = x^4$
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ D(X) = -1$

You're understanding that I'm going the wrong way.

And starting with a function where the denominator would have its square root removed by a conjugate:
$\int \frac{(x^4 - 1)(x - \sqrt{x})}{x^2 - x}.dx$
wouldn't help me that much: it's leading me to a developed numerator such as: $x^5 - (\sqrt{x})x^4 - x + \sqrt{x}$ which, I guess, would make the identification even harder.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the answer given by your textbook is wrong. Finding the derivative of the "*answer*":
$$d(x^5/5 - \ln x + (2/3)x^{3/2} + C)\over dx$$
$$\frac{d(x^5/5)}{dx} - \frac{d(\ln x)}{dx} + \frac23 \times \frac{d(x^{3/2})}{dx}$$
$$\color{red}{x^4 - {1\over x} + \sqrt{x}}$$ which is not equal to the original expression in the question. This is how I did the integral:
$$\int \frac{x^4 - 1}{x+\sqrt x} dx$$
Factorisation usually helps:
$$\int \frac{(x^2 - 1)(x^2 + 1)}{\sqrt x(\sqrt x+1)} dx$$
$$\int \frac{(x - 1)(x+1)(x^2 + 1)}{\sqrt x(\sqrt x+1)} dx$$
$$\int \frac{(\sqrt x - 1 )(\sqrt x + 1)(x+1)(x^2 + 1)}{\sqrt x(\sqrt x+1)} dx$$
This helps us simplify the expression (as the $\sqrt x + 1$ cancels out:
$$\int \frac{(\sqrt x - 1 )(x+1)(x^2 + 1)}{\sqrt x} dx$$Notice that you still have the nasty square root, so substitution might help. Set $u = \sqrt x$. We have ${du\over dx} = {1 \over 2\sqrt x}$. So, $dx = 2\sqrt x du$. Performing substitution:
$$\int \frac{(u - 1)(u^2+1)(u^4+1)}{\sqrt x} \times 2\sqrt x du$$Thus, we get an easy expression:
$$2 \int (u - 1)(u^2+1)(u^4+1) du$$
$$2 \int(u^7 - u^6 + u^5 - u^4 + u^3 - u^2 + u -1) du$$ which is a piece of cake from here. Just use $\int u^n du = {u^{n+1} \over n+1}$ from here, to arrive at the answer.
You get:
$$2(u^8/8 - u^7/7 + u^6/6 - u^5/5 + u^4/4 - u^3/3 + u^2/2 - u) + C$$Putting the value of $u$ back:
$$\color{green}{\frac{x^4}4 - \frac{2x^3 \sqrt x}{7} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{2x^2\sqrt x}{5} + \frac{x^2}2 - \frac{2x \sqrt x}{3} + x - 2\sqrt x + C}$$Well I suppose (correct me if I'm wrong!) this is the final answer.

**Edit:**
Let's find the derivative to verify the answer:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^4}4 - \frac{2x^3 \sqrt x}{7} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{2x^2\sqrt x}{5} + \frac{x^2}2 - \frac{2x \sqrt x}{3} + x - 2\sqrt x + C\right)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^4}{4}\right) - \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{2x^{7/2}}{7}\right) + \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^3}{3}\right) - \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{2x^{5/2}}{5}\right) + \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right) - \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{2x^{3/2}}{3}\right) + \frac{dx}{dx} - \frac{d}{dx}\left(2x^{1/2}\right)$$
$$x^3 - x^{5/2} + x^2 - x^{3/2} + x - x^{1/2} + 1 - x^{-1/2}$$Which is:
$$x^3 - x^2\sqrt x + x^2 - x\sqrt x + x - \sqrt x + 1 - \frac1{\sqrt x}$$
$$x^2(x - \sqrt x) + x(x - \sqrt x) + 1(x - \sqrt x) + \frac1x(x - \sqrt x)$$Rewriting:
$$\frac{x^3(x - \sqrt x) + x^2(x - \sqrt x) + x(x - \sqrt x) + 1(x - \sqrt x)}{x}$$
$$\frac{(x - \sqrt x)(x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)}{x}$$
$$\frac{\sqrt x(\sqrt x - 1)(x+1)(x^2+1)}{x}$$
$$\frac{(\sqrt x - 1)(x+1)(x^2+1)}{\sqrt x}$$
Multiplying both numerator and denominator by $(\sqrt x + 1)$
$$\frac{(\sqrt x + 1)(\sqrt x - 1)(x+1)(x^2+1)}{\sqrt x(\sqrt x + 1)}$$
$$\frac{(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)}{x+\sqrt x}$$
$$\frac{(x^2 - 1)(x^2+1)}{x+\sqrt x}$$
$$\color{green}{\frac{x^4 - 1}{x+\sqrt x}}$$

Comment: I thank you a lot for your explanations (I working hard to understand them, especially around the $\frac{du}{dx}$ and because I have removed the square from the denominator sooner than you. But it seems that your answer, when derived leads to $\frac{(\sqrt{x}-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{(x+1)(x^2+1)}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}-1)} = \frac{x^3+x^2+x+1}{x-\sqrt{x}}$, and not to the initial function. Even if I could manage the expression to have a its denominator $\sqrt{x}+1$ instead of $\sqrt{x}-1$ with a conjugate, I should never find again a numerator starting by $x^4$.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan see my edit where I find the derivative of the answer.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan I'll try to make  the $\frac{du}{dx}$ thing more clear: We know $u = \sqrt x \implies u^2 = x$. Taking derivative w.r.t $x$, $\frac d{dx}u^2 = \frac{dx}{dx}$ so, $\frac{d}{du}u^2 \times \frac{du}{dx} = 1$ by the chain rule. We get: $2u \frac{du}{dx} = 1 \implies 2\sqrt x \frac{du}{dx} = 1$ since $u = \sqrt x$, so we get $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac1{2 \sqrt x}$ same answer

Comment: You deserved a reward bounty for all your explanations.

Comment: Glad I could be helpful!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the solution is totally wrong
$$\frac d {dx}\left(\frac{x^5}{5} - \log{x} + \frac{2}{3}\,x^\frac{3}{2} + C\right)=x^4+\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{x}$$

If you want to compute this integral, let $x=t^2$ and perform the long division.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! And to have discovered that the solution was wrong. I am disappointed by so many books where authors don't take the time to verify their results with a calculator, (when many do formal calculation today).

Comment: Just remember: misprints do happen, authors are human. The solution given here is a good tool to have: remove square roots by that change of variable.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan it must have been a misprint. I am inclined to think that the author _did_ use an integral calculator, but instead of typing (x^4 - 1)/(x+ \sqrt x) (which the calculator would've translated as : $(x^4 - 1)\over (x+ \sqrt x)$, he typed x^4 - 1/x + \sqrt x, which the calculator translated as $x^4 - {1\over x} + \sqrt x$.

Comment: that's the importance of parentheses!

Answer (score 1):

You say it leads you to:$$\int \frac{(x^4-1)(x-\sqrt x)}{x^2-x}\,dx$$ "which doesn't help much."

But it does help, if you notice that $x-1$ is a common factor of the numerator and denominator, giving: $$\int\frac{(x^3+x^2+x+1)(x-\sqrt x)}x\,dx$$

This integral is not hard.

But the book's answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

-2 Sqrt[x] + x - (2 x^(3/2))/3 + x^2/2 - (2 x^(5/2))/5 + x^3/3 - (
2 x^(7/2))/7 + x^4/4+C is the answer/solution as given by the techniques suggested by others.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).